# .htaccess rewriting with THE_REQUEST

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to prevent Apache from urldecoding %20 from my URLs because I use parts of the URL as parameters in my Controllers.

My .htaccess used to look like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And that was basically perfect except for %20 being decoded when URLs like "/path/to/something%20interesting/" where accessed.

I read, that THE_REQUEST provides a non-decoded URL-string. Now I'm trying to use the path-part of THE_REQUEST for my rewrite. I wrote a regular expression that matches the part of THE_REQUEST I want, but I don't know, how to pass the string to the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(/([a-zA-Z0-9/\-_()]|(%20))+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava yes, it does. I FILTER_SANITIZE_URL the string, so this spaces get stripped. But I need those spaces and I also want to filter for security reasons.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that filtering is not needed? I mean, parts of `$_GET['uri']` are being used as parameters in my app. Is there no risk of malicious code entered via the requested path breaking something?

Comment: Sorry. I don't follow. How does this approach prevent the spaces from being stripped?

Comment: I switched to `strip_tags()`. That solves my immediate problem for now, but I'd actually like to understand how to use THE_REQUEST in a .htaccess